# swap dynamic allocated array error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I try to swap 2 dynamic allocated array that have different capacity. I try to use:

```
int *temp = arr1;
int arr1 = arr2;
int arr2 = temp;
```

However this approach doesn't work. So I try different approach:

```
ItemType *temparr1 = new ItemType[other.capacity];
std::copy(setMember, setMember+capacity, temparr1);
ItemType *temparr2 = new ItemType[this->capacity];
std::copy(setMember, setMember+capacity, temparr2);
delete [] this->setMember;
delete [] other.setMember;
other.setMember = temparr1;
this->setMember = temparr2;
```

Unfortunately, this approach cast an error message :"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Hw1.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Hw1.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded."

any idea how can I swap dynamic allocated array? thx

Comment: `std::swap(arr1, arr2);`

Comment: `int *temp = arr1; int arr1 = arr2;` would result in a multiple definition of `arr1`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: but if one is in a `{}` that the other is not in, it compiles anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't swap the memory because it's not the same size (assuming `other.capacity` is different than `this->capacity` - if it was, you wouldn't get the runtime error).

Use `std::vector` instead.

If you just want to swap what the pointers point to:

```
int *temp = arr1;
arr1 = arr2;
arr2 = temp;
```

or

```
std::swap(arr1, arr2);
```

Again, note that these won't swap the actual memory, but the values of the pointers.

Observe the missing `int` declarations which you initially had.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach should work simply remove the `int` before the second and third line(don't decalre new integer variables, assign to arrays). Also as pointed out by hmjd you may use `std:swap`.

If you want to use the second approach you show using std::copy, you will have to first resize the array, as it is possible that its capacity is insufficient.